# Cork in a falling bucket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-fall

A bucket of water containing a cork held down on the bottom by some mechanism is dropped from the top of a building. The cork is released at the moment the bucket is dropped. Where is the cork right before the bucket strikes the ground?

Comment: This is a homework-like exercise. Site policy for such questions requires you to show your attempt to answer the question and to ask about a conceptual difficulty.

Comment: If the cork is made of lead, it is still at the bottom of the bucket...

Comment: Depending on the length of the drop, the water and cork will likely be nowhere near the bucket when it hits the ground.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually seen a demo of this in a physics class room.  The cork floats because of the buoyant force.  However, "g" is in the equation for buoyant force because the buoyant force is equal to the **weight** of the displaced fluid, and falling water has no weight while it is in free fall.  This means that the cork stays on the bottom of the bucket until the bucket actually stops free falling (until it hits the ground).  Then and only then will the cork float to the water's surface.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Equivalence Principle, it is impossible to distinguish (by a local experiment) a uniform gravitational acceleration and an acceleration of the coordinate system. In particular, the laws of physics for a freely falling coordinate system are the same as for a system with no gravitational field. Since in the empty space the cork would remain at the bottom of the bucket (no gravitational field implies no pressure gradient and therefore no buoyancy force), the Equivalence Principle assures that the same happens for a freely falling bucket near the surface of the Earth.